# A subgroup of the alternating group $A_4$ compromising all products of two disjoint 2-cycles?!

Tags: group-theory

I need some clarification here. How can such a subgroup contain the identity?

Comment: Explain yourself please - a 2-cycle is an odd permutation, so it cannot be an element of $A_4$.

Comment: @NickyHekster Fixed the title. I meant to say "all disjoint products of 2-cycles"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you well, the only possibility is that the set $\{(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)\}$ belongs to this subgroup of $A_4$ and in particular the subgroup *generated* by these elements, which only adds the identity element $(1)$ (take any element of the set and square it!). The subgroup is by the way isomorphic to $V_4$.

Comment: But how can $(1)$ be rewritten as two disjoint 2-cycles? The square of the elements you specified would not be a disjoint product, right? It seems like the "subgroup" is not closed according to the definition "all products of two disjoint 2-cycles"?

Comment: $(1)$ is a certainly not a 2-cycle, that is right. It is a 1-cycle. But note the difference between the indicated *set*, and *subgroup*. It is maybe a matter of speech - the word *comprising* (not *compromising* as you stated) - means implicitly "generated by".